# Highline if the values repeat in another three columns

Tags: excel, sum, key-value-store

Folks, I've got the following sheet:

[image]

I need to conditional format cells if the values in the columns `B`, `C` and `D` repeat in the Columns `H`, `I` and `J`, but ONLY if they are in a sequence.

For example, if I entered an expense of 12 for day 1 and the description of A, and repeat all these values in columns H, I, J it will automatically highlight the line.

I can not solve this, I've tried a lot, but no success.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: It is expected to show some original effort beyond *i've tried a lot, but no success*. There are many unanswered questions from the desciption of your problem and if you have shown what you had tried so far, many of these could have been answered. This isn't a game of 'twenty questions'; you show us what you've done and describe the problems you have encountered and we offer assistance.

Comment: Sure, i've tried this:

=COUNTIFS($C$7:$D, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 4))) + COUNTIFS($I$7:$J, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 4))) >1

It counts the repeated values, but it's not considering the 3 conditionals.. it's just check if there's something repeated in the interval. The problem with this is that, when i add a single description repeated, it consideres like a "repetition"and highline :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($H:$H,$B2,$I:$I,$C2,$J:$J,$D2)>0
```

[image]

Comment: It's almost working, but it's highlighting the whole line, i wish it highline the other column with the same value    :(
Any idea?

Comment: Which columns do you want highlighted?

Comment: You want to limit the `Applies To:` range in the Rules Manager to only the columns you want affected.  As above only the columns C and D are in the applies to.

Comment: I think I know what you want; you will need another rule for the other columns with the formula reversed to test the other columns.  So two different formulas on two different areas.  they cannot be the same formula.

Comment: ![http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20160612/y6htwi1thc7d.jpg][] 

Ow no, sorry, i mean, that columns are correct, but take a look, in the second columns H,I,J it's not highlighting the cells with the same value, it's highlininh the same "line". :(

Comment: Like I said in the last comment you will need a seperate rule for them using: `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$H2,$C:$C,$I2,$D:$D,$J2)>0` as the formula.

Comment: Cool, i invert it as u suggest and it works like magic! Thank you a lot folk! 

:)